# How to write to localStorage and post textarea with one click?

Tags: javascript, python, html

I have a handler `/choice` with a textarea field and `/choicehandler` that writes the information returned to database. But before posting the form I want to write a user name to `localStorage`.

This is the form:

```
<form name="choice_form" action="/choicehandler" method="post">
  <textarea name="choice" rows="7" cols="50"></textarea><br />
  <input type="submit" value="submit your choice">
</form>
```

On click I want to assign a username to the user and write it to `localStorage` with `writeToStorage()`:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var count = 0;

function writeToStorage()
{ 
    user = "user" + count;
    count++;
    localStorage.setItem("chooser", user);
};

</script>
</head>
```

What I am confused about is how to use `onclick="writeToStorage()"` to call the `writeToStorage()` and at the same time have `action="/choicehandler"` in the form.

What is the correct way to achieve something like this. I am working with Google App Engine (Python) and I will add the ajax call to `/choicehandler` later after I solve this.

As a summary, I want to write the javascript variable `user` to `localStorage` and `post` the textarea to `/choicehandler` with one click.

**UPDATE**

I am trying [john_doe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107351/how-to-write-to-localstorage-and-post-textarea-with-one-click/8107425#8107425) but `writeToStorage()` is never fired. What am I doing wrong? The full code for the handler is below:

```
class Choice(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write("""
<html>
  <head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var count = 0;

function writeToStorage()
{ 
    alert("count: " + count);
    user = "user" + count;
    //this line was giving an error; now it is fixed
    //alert("user: " + user and "count: " + count);
    alert("user: " + user + " and count: " + count);
    count++;
    localStorage.setItem("chooser", user);

};
</script>

  </head>
  <body>


<form name="choice_form" id="choice_form" action="/choicehandler" method="post" onsubmit="writeToStorage()">
  <textarea name="choice" rows="7" cols="50"></textarea><br />
  <input type="submit" value="submit your choice">
</form>""")

        self.response.out.write("""
  </body>
</html>""")
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current technique?

Comment: I am not clear where or how to use `onclick="writeToStorage()"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let your function get invoked right before the form gets submitted.

```
<form name="choice_form" action="/choicehandler" method="post" onsubmit="writeToStorage()">
  <textarea name="choice" rows="7" cols="50"></textarea><br />
  <input type="submit" value="submit your choice">
</form>
```

Comment: I've been trying this but `writeToStorage()` never fires. What am I doing wrong? I updated the question with the code I am trying.

Comment: I found the error, there was a misplaced quote in one of the alerts, now it is all working. Thanks.

Comment: can you explain with more details what happens here when form is submitted? When I try to get the POST and XHR I cannot get them both at the same time, it seems that the form is sent twice. This is the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114926/can-i-test-xmlhttprequest-in-sdk-with-localhost

Answer (score 1):

you can change your function a bit (lots of ways to do this). Add an Id to your form (id="choice_form"), then add a line that submits your form:

```
function writeToStorage() {      
    user = "user" + count;     
    count++;    
    localStorage.setItem("chooser", user); 
    document.getElementById("choice_form").submit();
}
```

Comment: I tried this version and john_doe's and `writeToStorage` is not firing. I tried `<button type="button" onclick="writeToStorage()">write to storage</button>` and that did not help either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: there was a misplaced quote in one of the alerts, now it is working. Thanks.