# Can I test XMLHttpRequest() in SDK with localhost?

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, xmlhttprequest

The following code does not seem to work because when I try to get the "chooser" in Google App Engine (Python) it is undefined:

```
chooser = self.request.get("chooser")
self.response.out.write("chooser: %s " % chooser)
#returns "chooser:" without any value
```

Is this valid javascript?

```
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("chooser", user);

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  //is it ok to test this with localhost?
  xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8086/g/choicehandler", true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function (aEvt) {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){ 
      console.log("request 200-OK");
    }
    else {
      console.log("connection error");
    }
  };
  xhr.send(formData);
```

Is the problem with the XHR call or with the App?

**UPDATE**

I am including the code in `/choice` to clarify what "chooser" is as per Daniel Roseman's comment:

In `/choice` handler I have `writeToStorage()` which assigns a username in the form `user1, user2` and so on, and writes that to `localStorage`.

After writing user name to `localStorage` I also need to write it to database in the app, and I use `xhr` to send it to `/g/choicehandler` handler.

So, "chooser", I believe is a string, made of

```
var user = "user" + count;
```

I copy `/choice` handler below:

```
class Choice(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write("""
<html>
  <head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var count = 0;

function writeToStorage()
{ 
  var user = "user" + count;
  count++;
  localStorage.setItem("chooser", user);

  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("chooser", user);

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8086/g/choicehandler", true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function (aEvt) {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){ 
      console.log("request 200-OK");
    }
    else {
      console.log("connection error");
    }
  };
  xhr.send(formData);  
};

</script>

  </head>
  <body>


<form name="choice_form" id="choice_form" action="/g/choicehandler" method="post" onsubmit="writeToStorage()">
  <textarea name="choice" rows="7" cols="50"></textarea><br />
  <input type="submit" value="submit your choice">
</form>

  </body>
</html>""")
```

**UPDATE 2**

I noticed in the logs that the text from textarea which is "choice" and "chooser" which is sent with xhr are not shown together, one of them is always without a value:

```
INFO ... chooser: user0 choice: 
INFO ... chooser:  choice: abcd

INFO ... chooser: user0 choice: 
INFO ... chooser:  choice: efgh
```

This is the code for the above log:

```
chooser = self.request.get("chooser")
choice = self.request.get("choice")
logging.info("chooser: %s choice: %s" % tuple([chooser, choice]))


new_choice = User(
    choice = choice,
    owner = chooser)

new_choice.put()
```

so in the datastore i see "chooser" and "choice" written in 2 different rows. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is OK as long as the page using this script is also served from localhost:8086

Comment: What is 'chooser' supposed to be?

Comment: Are you sure `user` has a value in your javascript? Have you tried replacing it with a string literal for testing?

Comment: @DanielRoseman; I updated the question to clarify "chooser"

Comment: @NickJohnson; I have several alerts in script that I deleted for clarity, and I see that a user value is written to localStorage as expected. And I also tried `localStorage.getItem("chooser");` in /choicehandler and this gets the user name from localStorage.

Comment: @NickJohnson; I updated the question with log info. The value of "chooser" appears in the logs, but not with the value of textarea taken from the form. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think what happens is that `/choicehandler` is called twice once with the POST of the form and once by XHR. Do you think this is the case? If so how to send the POSTs without calling `/choicehandler` twice?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you're submitting the form twice. Once in writeToStorage via AJAX and also with the normal way with the the form. You will have to change two things.

1. `writeToStorage` has to return `false` as the last action
2. Change your `onsubmit` to `onsubmit="return writeToStorage()"`

This way you will prevent the default submission of your form, as it will be done via AJAX in writeToStorage