# How do I get the value of a textarea?

Tags: javascript, python, html, xmlhttprequest

This is a follow up to [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114926/can-i-test-xmlhttprequest-in-sdk-with-localhost). I am asking again because this seems more a javascript question than a Google App Engine question.

I have a form

```
<form name="choice_form" id="choice_form" method="post" action="/g/choicehandler" onsubmit="writeToStorage()">
  <textarea name="choice" rows="7" cols="50"></textarea><br />
  <input type="submit" value="submit your choice">
</form>
```

I want to take the value of this `textarea` and send it to the app with `formData`. I tried this

```
  var choice = document.getElementById("choice_form").value;
```

but I get "undefined" for the value of "choice". What am I doing wrong?

And also, if I understand correctly, the `/g/choicehandler` is called twice once by the form and once by the XHR. How do I fix that? Below is the handler:

```
class Choice(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write("""
<html>
  <head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var count = 0;

function writeToStorage()
{ 
  var user = "user" + count;
  count++;
  localStorage.setItem("chooser", user);
  var choice = document.getElementById("choice_form").value;

  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("chooser", user);
  formData.append("choice", choice);

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8086/g/choicehandler", true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function (aEvt) {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){ 
      console.log("request 200-OK");
    }
    else {
      console.log("connection error");
    }
  };
  xhr.send(formData);  
  //added this per Aaron Dufour's answer
  return 0;
};

</script>

  </head>
  <body>

//changed onsubmit like this: onsubmit="return writeToStorage(); as per Aaron Dufour's answer
<form name="choice_form" id="choice_form" action="/g/choicehandler" method="post" onsubmit="writeToStorage()">
  <textarea name="choice" rows="7" cols="50"></textarea><br />
  <input type="submit" value="submit your choice">
</form>

  </body>
</html>""")
```

**UPDATE**

See [Aaron Dufour's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116545/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-a-textarea/8116770#8116770) for the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, you're accessing the `form`, when the data you want is in the `textarea`.  If you give the `textarea` an ID, that's probably the easiest way to get to its value.

After much discussion, we determined that you don't need XHR at all.  Here's what your form should look like:

```
<form name="choice_form" id="choice_form" action="/g/choicehandler" method="post" onsubmit="writeToStorage()">
  <textarea name="choice" rows="7" cols="50"></textarea><br />
  <input type="hidden" name="chooser" id="form_chooser" />
  <input type="submit" value="submit your choice">
</form>
```

And now, we use the javascript function to edit the form before allowing it to be submitted:

```
var count = 0;

function writeToStorage()
{ 
  var user = "user" + count;
  count++;
  localStorage.setItem("chooser", user);

  document.getElementById("form_chooser").value = user;
};
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked the first time I tested it. But the second time and third time all values were absent again. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Zeynel I'm not sure.  Can you update with the code that might be the culprit?  Make sure you do a hard refresh so you have the new page.

Comment: Thanks, after hard refresh now I am getting the xhr values. But form data is sent also, so the `/choicehandler` is called twice: According to the log:

`INFO ... xhr_chooser: user0; xhr_textarea: abcd; post_from_form: 1234 
INFO ... "POST /g/choicehandler HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO ... xhr_chooser: xhr_textarea: post_from_form: 1234 `

Comment: @Zeynel Given that you never want the form to submit except through the `onsubmit` handler, you can just remove the `method` and `action` values for the `form` tag.  I'll update my answer to that effect.

Comment: ok, I did that, but I still need to redirect to /g/choicehandler. I am trying this but for some reason it is not working: `xhr.send(formData);
  
  window.location = "http://localhost:8086/g/choicehandler";
  return 0;` Thanks again.

Comment: @Zeynel Wait, you want to redirect to `/g/choicehandler` and send an AJAX request, but you only want to send data once?  Why are you using XHR, exactly?

Comment: `writeToStorage()` gives a user name to the new user and writes it to localStorage. Then I need to send that user name to /g/choicehandler to write to database. How do I send that "user" variable created by javascript function to python backend? I thought XHR was the way to go.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4962/discussion-between-aaron-dufour-and-zeynel)

Answer (score 4):

`choice_form` is the `<form>`, not the `<textarea>`.
You need to give the `<textarea>` an ID and use that ID instead.

Comment: Or use the textarea's name: `document.choice_form.choice.value` will do.

Comment: thanks. any comments about the second part of the question? what is wrong with the hxr? I've been testing it and once or twice I got the values sent by the xhr in the app but in every try the value sent by the form is always there. What am I doing wrong.

Comment: @Zeynel: You need to `return false` from the submit handler to prevent the default action.

Answer (score 3):

You can access the form formally using:

```
document.forms['choice_form']
```

or also:

```
document.forms.choice_form
```

Each form has an *elements* collection that is all the form controls. You can access them much the same way:

```
document.forms['choice_form'].elements['choice']
```

or

```
document.choice_form.choice
```

provided the names follow the rules for valid javascript identifiers. If they don't, you need to use square bracket notation:

```
document['choice_form']['choice']
```

all return a reference to the element named 'choice' in a form with name 'choice_form'. So to get the value:

```
document.choice_form.choice.value
```

Answer (score 2):

(Some great answers here, but I haven’t seen one that puts it together with what you have…)

Since a form can have more than one input, you need to access `value` on a particular one. There are a few ways to do this, but the most straightforward might be to use the form’s `elements` property (only forms have this!):

```
document.getElementById("choice_form").elements.choice.value
```